# Calculating volume which formula in Numbers?

Tags: ios, ipad, numbers

We are tracking the water depth of our cistern and would like to input the volume of water as a function. We have the measurements of the cistern so the only changing variable is the depth. Which formula in Numbers on iPad should we use?

Comment: Could you show us what you have? We specialize in helping people understand pages and not maths. This seems like an algebra/geometry homework without some more details on what exactly has you stumped.

Comment: No formula needed, this is just a simple calculation.  Like @bmike said, what is it that has you stumped?  How to create the calculation?  Or how Numbers calculations work?

Answer (score 1):

Basic math.

- [length]<sup>3</sup> (Length × width × height)
- For a cylinder,  * radius<sup>2</sup> * height.

When the depth measurement changes, change the corresponding depth amount and **Numbers** will recalculate.

Just be sure to use the same units of measure for all dimensions.

---

[image: calculate volume]